# Xbox One controller and VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, 15.04, games, gamepad

I connected an Xbox One controller to a PC equipped with Ubuntu 15.04 and the system recognizes it perfectly. The problem is that VirtualBox with Win10 (to stream Xbox games) fails to recognizes it. I also tried to install xboxdrv to see if something changed, but nothing. The pad works perfectly under Ubuntu, I have also tested it with jtest-gtk, but there's no way to do something to make VirtualBox working with it. After all, I have tried to create a USB filter on VirtualBox settings with the parameters taken from **lsusb** but absolutely nothing happens.

Any idea to make the Xbox One pad working under VirtualBox?

Comment: Have you thought about dual-booting instead?  That's much simpler and less resource intensive than having a VM.

Comment: I'm not interested in dual-booting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the settings to pass through USB devices to guests on an Windows host in VirtualBox?

A note of caution: USB support is only available in the closed-source edition of VirtualBox.

On youtube a person managed to get it working by editing the registry a bit. It's a little bit of a cumbersome process but it's reported to work.

See below video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDAxrVzBTmM

Comment: My host is Ubuntu 15.04 and this trick not works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Try:

1. Make sure that `virtualbox` is closed
2. `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER`
3. `sg vboxusers virtualbox`